# How to merge the given two line awk code into one line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, replace, sed

The data in my file are stored in columns. These columns contain specific values separated by ':'. I want to update the value if there is pipe '|' in either 6th or 8th column.

**A line of my data is as follows:**

```
0/1:38,59:97:99:.:.:2015,0,1366:0|1:.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.:1311:|:0.5  0/1:89,56:145:99:0|1:5238_G_C:2074,0,5187:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:31,65:96:99:.:.:2208,0,1170:.:.:.:.:.   0/1:58,74:132:99:.:.:2457,0,1761:.:.:.:.:.
```

In the input file there is a pipe in the first column at 8th field. So, the value of the 1st field gets updated by the value in the 8th field. There will be a pipe either at 6th or 8th field not at both. Pipe at other field positions doesn't matter. **For the above input the expected output is:**

```
0|1:38,59:97:99:.:.:2015,0,1366:0|1:.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.:1311:|:0.5  0/1:89,56:145:99:0|1:5238_G_C:2074,0,5187:.:.:.:.:. 0/1:31,65:96:99:.:.:2208,0,1170:.:.:.:.:.   0/1:58,74:132:99:.:.:2457,0,1761:.:.:.:.:.
```

***And, I have the following code:***

**First I update the value from 6th field**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,f,/:/); if (f[6]~/\|/) sub(/^[^:]+/,f[6],$i) } }1' 2ms01e_only.pHASER01.vcf > 2ms01e_PG_6th.pHASER01.vcf
```

**and then update value from 8th position**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($i,f,/:/); if (f[8]~/\|/) sub(/^[^:]+/,f[8],$i) } }1' 2ms01e_PG_6th.pHASER01.vcf > 2ms01e_PG_transfered.pHASER01.vcf
```

**How can I write above code (two separate lines) as one line? So, I can update the value in the first field if there is a pipe either in 6th or 8th field. btw, The updated value is pulled from 6th or 8th field**. The given code does what I want to do but I have to do it two time. I just want a code that is one line.

Thanks,

Comment: Add the expected output for your input in question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your `awk` logic is not doing what your intending to do. State your expected output for a better solution.

Comment: Hi @Inian. I have updated the details in the question. Can you please remove the downvote from my question, if you did it? Thanks,

Comment: I did not down vote your question.

Comment: Ok, that fine. Does the added details in the question make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

**V2:**

If you just want those 2 codes combined, this is one way:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } 
           { 
               for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
                   split($i,f,/:/); 
                   if (f[6]~/\|/) 
                       sub(/^[^:]+/,f[6],$i);
                   if (f[8]~/\|/) 
                       sub(/^[^:]+/,f[8],$i);
               } 
           } 1' 2ms01e_only.pHASER01.vcf > 2ms01e_PG_6th.pHASER01.vcf
```

Untested.

Comment: Revisited. ````